# Reading text matlab without blocking the file

Tags: matlab

Is there a way to read a text file in matlab, without blocking the file.

so basically i want to read in read-only-mode and avoid blocking the files in case simultaneously another software is trying to updating/modify or delete them.

fopen/textscan will block the files.

Comment: What do you mean by "blocking the files"?

Comment: blocking another software from deleting/updating them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use Memory Mapping in MATLAB:

[Overview of Memory-Mapping](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/overview-of-memory-mapping.html)

> **Benefits of Memory-Mapping**
>
> The principal benefits of memory-mapping are efficiency, faster file
>   access, the ability to share memory between applications, and more
>   efficient coding.

There are some limitations. The file should be pretty well structured. I'm also not sure what happens if other application change the file size.